# Finding radius and center of circle with given two points

Tags: android, math, geometry, angle

Is it possible to find the radius and center of circle if I have two points on the circle?

[image]

Actually I want to place circles in positions as in pic. I just have the rectangle which is going to contain the circles. I want that these circles to be placed starting from left-center of rect to right-center in a circular manner. If need more explanation, kindly let me know...

Comment: This is still not sufficient. As already answered by Chris Taylor, you need more than two points to determine a circle and you have here only the two centers of the sides of the rectangle. You can think that the circle can be nearly aligned if the radius is very large or touch the ceiling of the rectangle if the radius is smaller. You must have another information, like the radius or a third point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. It takes three points to define a circle. Given any two points, there are infinitely many circles that pass through those two points.

For example:

[image]